# Get Config Value for Website Scope

Tags: configuration, scope, programming

How can I get a configuration value for a specific website?

There is `Mage::getStoreConfig()` but no `Mage::getWebsiteConfig()`.

*edit*:

I am exporting configuration data on website level - so somehow I want the website scope setting ...

Answer (score 16):

Usually, you're not supposed to do this.  `Mage::getStoreConfig()` will automatically return the store value, the website value, the global value, or the default value depending on the configuration of the field.

However, if you really need to disregard the store value and get the website value, you can do it this way:

```
Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getConfig('.../.../...')
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the websiteId. i.e. <br/> `Mage::app()->getWebsite($websiteId)->getConfig('web/unsecure/base_url')`

Answer (score 8):

This is a rare case, as settings are inherited to store level and usually `getStoreConfig()` takes the website settings into account.

You can use `Mage_Core_Model_Website::getConfig()` - but be a aware that there is a slight difference to `Mage_Core_Model_Store::getConfig()` where also some processing is being done (for example substitution of `{{...}}`) - this kind of 
substitution is not done on the website level.

If the value can only be changed on website level, another option would be to obtain just some random store of the website and then use `getStoreConfig()`.

Answer (score 6):

This can be derived using the specific website code if known.

```
$value = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('websites/[website_code]/section/group/field');
var_dump($value[0]);
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. You can get websites from `Mage::app()->getWebsites()` and the code from the website: `$website->getCode()`

Comment: Good stuff @benmarks. I agree, this should be marked as the right answer. I know it's not common to get a config value by website but in some cases it is.. for example, I needed to do this when running an export of products by website in a cron job task.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but as far as I remember, the configuration scope is always bound to stores.
If you set a value on a website level, it will be available on any store of that website unless you set a different value on the store level.

Say you have website A and store A1 and A2 are stores for that website.
Assume that A has the value 5 for a given property

Then `Mage::getStoreConfig()` will return 5 for that property both for A1 and A2.
If you set the property to 3 for A1, then
`Mage::getStoreConfig()` will return 3 for A1 and 5 for A2 for that property.

Comment: You are perfectly right - but: I am exporting configuration data on website level - so somehow I want the website scope setting ... I know this is a quite rare case.

Comment: @Alex You should probably mention that in your question, too ;)