# get system config data in website,store and default scope

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, system-config

I have created the custom groups and fields under System->Configuration->Design
I used the below event.

```
<admin_system_config_changed_section_design>
    <observers>
        <custom>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Custon_Custom_Observer</class>
            <method>save</method>
            </custom>
    </observers>
</admin_system_config_changed_section_design>
```

There are three types of scope in magento.

1) Default

2) Websites

3) Stores

I want all the values of my custom fields in admin panel to store the values in custom table.
[image]

for example,
you get description field value in store level.

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('design/custom/description');
```

I want the above value in website level and current store level.
I have tried [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/760/get-config-value-for-website-scope)

Comment: It seems there are 2 questions. One is to save sys/conf data in a custom table, one is how to get the value of sys/conf on different levels. Is that correct?

Comment: If get the value I will save in my custom table

Comment: http://alanstorm.com/magento_loading_config_variables refer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config.xml,

```
 <global>
    <events>
        <admin_system_config_changed_section_design>
            <observers>
                <custom>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Custon_Custom_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveSystemConfig</method>
                    </custom>
            </observers>
        </admin_system_config_changed_section_design>
    </events>
 </global>
```

In observer.php,

```
public function saveSystemConfig(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $postData = $observer->getEvent()->getData();

    if (is_null($postData['store']) && $postData['website']) //check for website scope
    {
        $scopeId = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($postData['website'])->getId();
        $description  = Mage::app()->getWebsite($scopeId)->getConfig('design/custom/description');
        $currentScope = 'websites';
    }
    elseif($postData['store']) //check for store scope
    {
        $scopeId =   Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($postData['store'])->getId();
        $description  = Mage::app()->getStore($scopeId)->getConfig('design/custom/description');
        $currentScope = 'stores';
    }
    else //for default scope
    {
        $scopeId = 0;
        $description  = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/social-meta-tags/design/custom/description')
        $currentScope = 'default';
    }
}
```

From the above you can get individual field values in all scopes.